# Пишу проект на Qt. Где нужно указать, что используется ПО с открытым исходным кодом?

Tags: лицензирование, opensource

Здравствуйте. Пишу проект для себя (если кому-то будет интересно, то и для людей) с использованием Qt. Qt под GPLv3, мой проект под MIT. Так вот, где мне нужно указать, что используется ПО с открытым исходным кодом (в данном случае Qt)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно читал документацию, то нужно сделать так

- в корневой каталог положите копии лицензий Qt и MIT (той, которую Вы используете)
- создайте файл LICENSE.txt, где напишите, что это Ваш проект под лицензией MIT и Вы используете Qt под GPLv3
- во всех *своих* файлах в верху добавьте короткую вставку с указанием авторства, даты создания, лицензии и подобного.
- там, где добавить вставку невозможно (к примеру, папка с картинками), вставьте текстовый документ с подобных текстом (картинки созданы таким то, лицензия такая то).
- также, неплохо добавить в пункт меню "помощь" рядом с " о программе" пункт "о Qt", с вызовом стандартного окошка.

в любом случае, всегда можно им написать напрямую и уточнить детали - http://qt.digia.com/licensing/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ
Насколько я помню, для того, что-бы применить MIT лицензию, не нужно в каждом файле ничего писать.
А что, если в файл LICENSE.txt засунуть текст лицензии MIT, а после приписать, что используется Qt под GPLv3 и предоставить тут-же текст этой лицензии?

Comment: тут возникает вопрос в том, распространяется ли на лицензию сама лицензия. Поэтому лучше лицензию не модифицировать. Может просто вставить ссылки на нужные лицензии?

В любом случае, в файле LICENSE.txt я как-либо образом перечислил файлы, которые попадают под MIT лицензию и какие не Ваши. Может даже в виде "вот эти файлы - это от Qt (GPLv2), эти - с дистрибутива gentoo (лицензия такая то), а все остальное - мое, по лицензии MIT". Тогда не будет проблем.

Comment: спасибо, вроде, все понятно

Comment: Прочитал про еще одну лицензию: LGPL.
Насколько я понял, там вообще ничего указывать не нужно, так что, думаю, выбор сделан в пользу LGPL

Comment: @rabbitinspace как всё прошло с LGPL? Потребовалось ли хоть какие-нибудь изменения в файлах проекта и/или упоминания для использования Qt в рамках этой лицензии?